# How do I prevent file naming restarts on Nikon D5200?

Tags: nikon, filenames

I have noticed something peculiar on my Nikon D5200.  If I take a set of images and remove them from the card, the next batch will start again at DSC_0001.  My older non DSLR camera would continue to increase the number over time and not reset.

Is there a way to keep the numbers from resetting when the images are removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Page 162 [in the manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5200RM_NT%2811%2901.pdf). Go to the *Custom Settings* menu and change option `d4`, "File Number Sequence", to *On*.

When this option is off, filenames are reset when you change exposure or reformat the card. With it on, they continue where you left off. An option to reset the count is also available in the same menu.